# How to represent the flow of a real-time web application

Tags: uml, flowchart

I am writing my thesis and need to represent the process flow of my application. I need to have a diagram that represents the flow of each process in my application. How do I represent an application which is meant to be "real-time". I have a shared whiteboard where whatever a user draw/write is reflected on the whiteboard of the other participants in the same room. For example if a user draw a rectangle, the coordinates and stuff will be sent to the other users for the rectangle to appear on their whiteboard. At the same time, the coordinates are stored in the database.

Comment: What are you after? Looking for a program that allows online communication?

Comment: i'm looking for what kind of diagrams (activity/flowchart...) is suitable to represent the flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are obviously many solutions, but a sequence diagram can show what you need. Assuming you have two representation boards and a central instance then a change on the first board will be communicated to the central instance. This broadcasts the change to all connected other boards which in turn show the change.

Of course there are a zillion different ways to implement the scenario. But with a seuqence diagram the involved communication can be shown best.

Below picture shows an example how this can look like:

[image]

You will need to draw quite a number of those to show how the concurrent board drawings are communicated.

Comment: The diagram you drew is easily understood and that's what i am after but sorry for the dumb question, what is the different size squares/rectangles meaning? I mean, do they mean something specific?

Comment: Filled ones a synchronous messages. Open ones asynchronous. There's more that can go into a SD, but that would take us too far off here.